# STAR "Standards for Technology in Automotive Retail" WCF Service Compliant

Tags: .net, wcf

I need to build a WCF service that comply with  STAR (Standards for Technology in Automotive Retail) model [link to wsdl and xsd](http://www.starstandard.org/images/SIGXMLSTAR5/STARSchemaRepository_Rev5114.zip). I am trying to use `svcutil.exe` tool generate the classes and endpoints but I am receiving errors like:

```
Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is 
dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding://wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2009/transport/bindings']/wsdl:binding[@name='starTransport']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2009/transport/bindings']/wsdl:service[@name='ProcessServiceAppointmentWebService']/wsdl:port[@name='ProcessServiceAppointmentStarTransport']
```

and

```
Error: There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:
Source:
Line: 2747 Column: 14
Validation Error: The 'http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9:Signature' element is not declared.
```

I tried different commands such as `svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd` but it doesn`t work properly as well.

Has anyone built any service using such standard before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the xsd2code extension for visual studio to covert the xsd files into classes, but you would still have to create the operation contracts etc.

Another option is to add the wsdl to soupUI, double click on the binding, this will show you a list of all the xsd files that are needed for that wsdl. Then using wsdl.exe pass in the wsdl and all the corresponding xsd files. This may get you closer to what you need, but would be very tedious if you are implementing a lot of their wsdl's.

Example:

```
wsdl /si /protocol:SOAP /l:CS /o:"c:\test\starfile" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\WSDL\WS4Templates\ProcessPartsPriceList.wsdl" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\BODs\Developer\ProcessPartsPriceList.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Nouns\PartsPriceList.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\Common\QualifiedDataTypes.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\OAGIS\CoreComponents\QualifiedDataTypes.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\OAGIS\CoreComponents\UnqualifiedDataTypes.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\OAGIS\Common\CodeLists.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\OAGIS\CoreComponents\CodeList_CurrencyCode_ISO_7_04.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\OAGIS\CoreComponents\CodeList_LanguageCode_ISO_7_04.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\OAGIS\CoreComponents\CodeList_MIMEMediaTypeCode_IANA_7_04.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\OAGIS\CoreComponents\CodeList_UnitCode_UNECE_7_04.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\Common\CodeLists.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\Common\CodeList_UnitsOfMeasureCode_XFront.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\Common\CodeLists_NMMA.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\OAGIS\Common\Components.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\OAGIS\Common\Meta.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\OAGIS\Common\Fields.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\Common\Meta.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\Common\DeprecatedComponents.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\Resources\Components\Common\Components.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\BODs\Developer\AcknowledgePartsPriceList.xsd" "C:\test\STAR\5.11.4\WSDL\WS4Templates\STARWSDLDataTypes4.xsd"
```

Comment: It could not be more precise. I indeed had generated all classes with xsd2code but the contracts are a real pain, that is why I was trying to use svcutil (or wsdl). But I didn't have figure how to get all xsd's involved with the files and SOAPUI really helped a lot. Now back to the boring job of implementing this weird wsdl's. Thank you very much @Popo